# Angular wait for rest API response in subscribe

Tags: angular, api

When I Try to get REST API Call thow client side (Angular) but when i subscribe this at that time function will runing not wait for response so please help for hold on function.

```
GetLookup(){
  let Country = this.countryService.GetAllCountry().toPromise();
}
```

OR

```
GetLookup(){
 this.countryService.GetAllCountry().subscribe((obj){
  let Country = obj;
})
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Use **async-await** concept.

```
    async GetLookup(){
  let Country = await this.countryService.GetAllCountry();
}
```

Comment: Angular is full plenty of Observables. Has no sense pass to Promise and use async. It's a work-around unnecessary